# Error Getting while opening the Infopath form

Tags: infopath

I have an InfoPath form published to a document library. 
When I tried to open the form by clicking on a new document from the document library, I am getting the following error. [image]

Please help me to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough information - does your form query another list? It looks like it does. Has that list been renamed/deleted? Are the correct permissions in place?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you query one or more SP Lists for your InfoPath form/fields. In your InfoPath designer, did you check the Data Connections for the form? You might want to select each data connection and click the Modify... button to walk through the connection to make sure it's OK.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Jeff Shall I have updated the Data connection and its working fine. Thank you so much